# What is mean accuracy and why is it a harsh metric for multi-label validation?

Tags: accuracy

The score method [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.score) for scikit-learn's SGDClassifier have the following description:

> Return the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.
>
> In multi-label classification, this is the subset accuracy which is a harsh metric since you require for each sample that each label set be correctly predicted.

What is meant by the terms **mean accuracy** and **subset accuracy**?

Could you please elaborate on why this is a harsh metric, perhaps with an example?